# Gradle Sync Failure in Fresh IntelliJ IDEA Install

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a new MBP (16" 2019). Downloaded a fresh copy of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1.1. Used SDKMan to install Java 11-zulu and latest Gradle, 6.4. Went to File->New-Project and chose Gradle. When it loads, I get a Sync error and gradle won't process in IntelliJ correctly. Everything works fine from the CLI. I tried with importing an existing gradle project, different Java and Gradle versions, all give the same vague error.

idea.log

> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: The newly
>   created daemon process has a different context than expected. It won't
>   be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: Java home
>   is different.

I've seen other questions about this but none of those solutions are working for me and I've never had this issue before, 10 years of using IDEA on OSX.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any related errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Please also share [a screenshot with your Gradle settings](https://i.imgur.com/dgN2UKF.png).

Comment: Updated with the requested info

Comment: How does the JDK configuration look like? Where do you have Java installed? See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218786 for the related issue. Does it help if you specify Java 11 for Gradle? See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239878#focus=streamItem-27-4131212.0-0.

Comment: This indeed was the problem and the solution. Not sure when/how this started happening, but thanks!

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239878#focus=streamItem-27-4131212.0-0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is likely caused by the incorrect Java home path specified for the JDK in IntelliJ IDEA. Make sure it points to the correct location like this:

```
/Users/rob/.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.1-zulu/zulu-14.jdk/Contents/Home
```

On macOS `/Contents/Home` part of the path is significant.

Comment: That works! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239878#focus=streamItem-27-4131212.0-0

Answer (score 1):

If some one are using macos with Sdkman use this version:  `sdk install java 8.0.322-librca` for sdk 1.8 or other correlated version from librca, because sdk fom zulu i always had this same problema in intellij idea with java/kotlin and gradlew...

Comment: This solved my problem (Apple M1 Pro chip, macOS 12.3) - grateful I didn't have to ask a colleague...