# Intellij complaining about JDK location

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bmSu.jpg)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3zS7.png)

As I attached 2 images, I am having trouble running my spring boot gradle project written in groovy.

As soon as I open the project, intellij tries to build the project and it fails saying Gradle Sync failed.

Since it is complaining about java home in the jdk setting, I was trying to change the path as my intellij expects. but as soon as I change it, it tells me that it cannot find android sdk location. and I have no idea why it cares about android sdk. This project is about spring batch job using gradle and groovy.

I have been searching why it happens for days now and online is talking about ardroid studio solution. and those solution do not apply to my problem.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio?

Comment: I am 100% sure that I am running IntelliJ. I do not have Android Studio installed on this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running Android Studio instead of IntelliJ IDEA.

The former doesn't support projects other than targeted for Android, so your project will not work there.

Make sure you run IntelliJ IDEA. You can get it at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: I am running IntelliJ IDEA. I do not have android studio installed on my machine.

Comment: Please share Help | About screen from your IDE.

Comment: And regarding the Gradle Java home issue with Zulu, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806948/104891 for the solution.

Comment: If it's IntelliJ IDEA, disable Android plug-in and see if it helps.

Comment: for some reason, i saw the android plugin enabled in my intellij. I dont remember installing it. but now it says, <project name>: failed. and starting gradle deamon...

Comment: sorry, actually now it works. so what i did was disable the android plugin and change the java version. thanks a lot. you made my day. but still i do not know why android plugin got installed out of nowhere.

Comment: Android plug-in is installed by default.